# Prevent Firebase logging "Analytics screen reporting is enabled" without disabling screen reporting?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, info.plist

In my Swift iOS app, I use Firebase Analytics. When running, I receive the following in the Xcode debugger log:

> `<AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002]` Analytics screen reporting is enabled.
> Call `+[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:]` to set the screen name or override the default screen class name.
> To disable screen reporting, set the flag `FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled` to `NO` (boolean) in the Info.plist

I want to avoid the above log in Xcode.

But I *do* want to keep `FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled` to `YES`, I want screen reporting as it works by default, without calling `+[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:]` in all my view controllers, using the name of the VC class as screen and class values.

I have also tried to add `FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled` key with the value of `YES` in my info.plist but that did not make a change.

Comment: What is that you want to achieve here? By default, you don't have to call setScreenName. If you want to remove that xcode log, then I have to tell you that that is printed by the library, you can't turn that off.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. In order to prove that, I will write a possible answer based on disassembling the relevant part of the Firebase SDK. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment from Tomo Norbert, I searched for the log ascii string in the Firebase frameworks, and I have found that the log is printed in the following framework:

```
GoogleAppMeasurement.framework
```

I called thin on the framework mach-o, chose the x86_64 architecture, then opened the resulting AR archive with "The Unarchiver". I searched again for the log ascii string in the folder, and I found 1 result:

```
UIViewController+APMScreenClassName_ef36a099a5d831581eb3abfc48885864.o
```

I imported the object into Hopper Disassembler, then searched for the log ascii string, and I found the relevant piece of assembly code:

[image: Hopper Disassembler assembly output]

It appears that Tomo Norbert is right. The library does just a NSClassFromString with the "FirAnalytics" string. If the result is not nil, it logs the researched string. Given that patching the framework is not a good way to go :) then I guess that it is impossible to prevent that log.